# Correct variable binding and avoiding SQL injection with SQLite.swift queries

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

The [SQLite.swift documentation for filtered queries](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#filtering-rows) gives this example:

```
users.filter(email.like("%@mac.com"))
// SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("email" LIKE '%@mac.com')
```

Since I want to search the database based on user input, I guess I could do the following:

```
let stringPrefix = userInput + "%"
users.filter(email.like(stringPrefix))
// SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("email" LIKE 'johndoe%')
```

Am I going about this the right way? With other SQLite environments in the past I have used [variable binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541454/correct-parameter-binding-for-select-where-like-using-fmdb) with `?` to avoid [SQL injection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_injection.htm). Is this done behind the scenes with SQLite.swift? I didn't see any information in the documentation except for a little bit about binding in the [Executing Arbitrary SQL](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#executing-arbitrary-sql) section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [this](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/7c6fe7ec02cafe32e6223d6fadf74b127373ae3e/SQLite/Typed/CoreFunctions.swift) source file :

```
@warn_unused_result public func like(pattern: String, escape character: Character? = nil) -> Expression<Bool> {
    guard let character = character else {
        return "LIKE".infix(self, pattern)
    }
    return Expression("(\(template) LIKE ? ESCAPE ?)", bindings + [pattern, String(character)])
}
```

This is just one of the overloads of the like function. The other overload looks quite similar, and does indeed also use parameter binding. Have a stroll in the source code to verify this yourself.

However, I would expect for you to have you internal tests to verify that SQLite injections are not possible.

Comment: Perhaps this is a separate question, but I'm not really sure what other internal tests I should be doing if parameter binding is already taken care of.